# Weird icon after software update

Tags: samsung, notification-icons

I've recently installed an automatic update on a Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android version 7.0) and since then a weird icon appeared on my top taskbar - a telephone receiver that rings, next to the 4g+ icon, ( screenshot attached) even though I am not calling anyone. Does anyone know what is that icon?

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: The phone is not in vibrate mode.

Comment: Check settings > sound > vibrate on ring. It is only meant to vibrate when ringing

Comment: Yes, that option is disabled. That means that the phone won't vibrate at all when ringing. I've tested it and it really does not vibrate.

Comment: I have turned vibrations on and the icon is still there, so it has nothing to do with vibrations

Comment: Tried that too. I set the volume to lowest, then to highest but the icon is still there.

Comment: It looks like the one for wi-fi calling, please check the related setting and observe if it disappears

Comment: Turned off WiFi, checked if the wifi calling is off and it is. Icon is still there. I even tried a phone reboot, but the icon is still there.

Comment: That does not help @xavier.

Comment: Sorry no ideas now..but I think @beeshyams is right. I just had a rather marginal call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it disappeard if I went to Connections-> mobile networks -> 4G call disable.